# Link button in Repeater control redirect to grid view

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

I am developing a web application where I have a repeater control. A link button is inside the repeater control. When the link button is clicked, I want it to redirect to a page which would be a data entry page for that particular user(which was clicked). It has to use the user-id/emplid and pre-populate some fields in the new page and other fields should be allowed for data-entry.

My question-

1. How should I redirect to the new data entry page? I haven't decided on the page yet. I am thinking that it would be a form page or grid view and would be a separate page.

Code:

```
    <asp:LinkButton ID="getDetails" OnCommand="getDetails_cmd" runat="server"
                        CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Emplid")%>
' Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"NAME")%>'
                            CommandName="Details"></asp:LinkButton>
```

1. After redirecting to the page, I guess, using the commandargument, I can get the emplid. an I pass multiple values? Say the keys for the page?
2. How should I update multiple tables in the page?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need handle `ItemCommand` event of `Repeater` control.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
        onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:LinkButton 
            ID="getDetails" 
            runat="server"
            Text='<%# Eval("NAME") %>'
            CommandName="cmd"
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Empid") %>'
            >
            </asp:LinkButton>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Handler of ItemCommand event,

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "cmd")
    {
        Session["empid"]=e.CommandArgument;
        Response.Redirect("~/page1.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks AVD. I tried this solution and it worked.Is it possible to send multiple values in a query string? Could you please let me know how to update multiple tables in a page? I am having a repeator control which would reference a package, would be read-only. The next section would be a detail view but would be update-able.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to direct to a new page, linkbutton is probably not the way to go since it does a postback to the same form normally, a standard hyperlink sending emplid in the querystring would work.  In the new page get the emplid from the querystring using `Request.Querystring("emplid")`.  As for saving to multiple tables, there are a number of ways to do that, one would be to wrap the multiple db update calls in a transactionscope.

Comment: Thanks David. I will try using a standard hyperlink control.Could you please explain what you meant by postback to the same page? For multiple tables in a page, can I have it in a grid view/data list? I basically, want to show some data for the employee and allow the user to enter data for few other sections. I am learning .NET, hence these simple questions.

Comment: yes, most server side controls (the <asp: ones) are designed to post back to the same page they are on, not to another one.  The "event" you get in the code behind is from the page doing a post to itself.  Not sure I understand the second question, yes, you can have each table have a grid view/data list if that is the question.